# How to handle Nodejs uncaughtException and unhandledRejection without termination using winston

Tags: node.js, express, winston

I am trying to find a way to catch all errors in my project and save them to the database as well as file log. I have create the following middleware which helps me in that need but the only problem I am facing using winston is that once uncaughtException or unhandledRejection is handled the app is terminated. Is there a way in winston to avoid this termination. All I want if for the them to be saved and delt later on.

```
const winston = require('winston');
```

`require('winston-mongodb');`

```
module.exports = function () {
process.on('unhandledRejection', (ex) => {
    //console.error('error', ex);
    throw ex; //Find better way
});//Catching uncaught exceptions with winston. We are using both file and db.
winston.exceptions.handle([
        new winston.transports.MongoDB({
            db: 'mongodb://localhost/web_logs',
            collection: 'exceptions',
            level: 'error'
        }),
        new winston.transports.Console,
        new winston.transports.File({filename: 'web-exceptions.log'})
    ]
);};
```

It is used in express after routes as

```
require('./middleware/exception-handler')();
```

It works well as intended but it terminates the app. How to avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do have an expressjs error handling middleware function ?
// something like this in ur index.js or app.js file

```
`app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
   console.error(err.stack)
   res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
 });`
```

winstonjs logs the errors, but they are not catch so it will crash your app